# Change of variable in integration

Tags: calculus, integration, change-of-variable

When integrating the following
$$y = \int \frac{dy}{dx}\,dx$$
We can apply change of variable which is based on the chain rule by multiplying $\frac{dx}{du}$ on the RHS.
$$y = \int \frac{dy}{dx}·\frac{dx}{du}\,du$$
But why does the equation still holds? I think the left hand side should also be affected. Because $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}$ but $\frac{dy}{dx} \not= \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{du}$. I want to solve it on my own but in order to  understand rigorous process it seems I should learn more advanced concepts like [differential form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form). And as I understand there are at least two standpoints about infinitesimal and limit for interpreting $\int \frac{dy}{dx}\,dx$. How to understand this?

Comment: You integrate $dy$ if you do things with forms. In general, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is meaningless if $dy$ and $dx$ are forms. Indeed, what does it mean to divide vectors on a vector space of dimension $>1$?

Comment: The easiest rule of thumb is to pretend like things written in Liebniz notation are fractions.  It's not true, but just about everything you'd try to do works the exact same.  So here it's like you multiplied inside the integral by $\frac {du} {du}$ which is like multiplying by 1.

Comment: Differential forms are actually not related to the infinitesimal picture at all, it is a completely different idea for approaching calculus. In this infinitesimal logic, this is simple to understand if you think of dx as a small length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Because $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}$ but $\frac{dy}{dx} \not= \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{du}$.

Indeed, but $\frac{dy}{du} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{du}$ .$$\begin{align}\int\mathrm d y&=\int\dfrac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d u}\mathrm d u\\&=\int\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm d x}\dfrac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d u}\mathrm d u\end{align}$$

Comment: It seems that you derived $\int dy$ from $\int \frac{dy}{dx}\,dx$ by canceling $dx$. But I thought $dx$ as a placeholder which says "we are integrating with respect to $x$". I think you didn't regard it as just a placeholder. How could $dx$ have meaning? Can you give me a keyword or any link? Thanks.